# How to create .appxuploade

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, package

I have published my app in windows phone store now i want to publish the same app in windows store for that i need .appxuploade file.i have previously used phonegap to create the xap file.So can some one help me how to create .appxuploade file

Comment: Any solution found here ?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, right click your Windows Store project. Go to `Store -> Create App Packages`. Follow the instructions there.

Otherwise, you can run MsBuild from the command line. You can use `/t:Publish`. When uploading, you don't *need* a `.appxupload` file. You can upload a `.appx`. The `.appxupload` is really just a zipped `.appx` and `.appxsym` (public symbols), renamed to '.appxupload'.

The .appx should be in the AppxPackage folder in the project folder.

Comment: i don't want to use visual studio.is there any other way.

Comment: Added an additional method

Comment: i don't even have idea about msbuild .Is there any chance to get the appx file from xap file .

Comment: No. The Xap file is build for Windows Phone and contains a different structure and build target than the Windows Store app (including things like a different app manifest). Appx is for Windows Store projects and requires being built on their own.

Comment: ok thanks.i am going with the visual studio and am unable to find the store option in the menu.my system has windows 7 is it okay or should have windows 8 as compulsion.

Comment: I believe that is the case, yes.